# One more field validation using passport.js LocalStrategy

Tags: node.js, mongodb, passport.js

I am using passport.js LocalStrategy to validate username and password. But now i have one more field to validate that is `active: true/false`(whether user is active or not). Below code shows validation of username and password.

### app.js

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField: 'username', 
    passwordField: 'password'},
    function(username, password, done) {
        User.findOne({ name : username}, function(err, user) {
            if (!user){
                return done(null, false,{message: 'Incorrect username' });
            } 

            if(user){
                var validPassword = user.comparePassword(password);

                if(!validPassword){
                    return done(null, false,{message: 'Incorrect password' });
                }
            }           
            return done(null, user);
        });       
    }
));

router.post('/pages/auth/login', function(req, res, next) {
    passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info) {
        if (user === false) {
            return res.json({
                success:false,
                message: info.message,
            });
        } else {
            req.login(user, function(err) {
                return res.json({
                    success:true,
                    Id:req.sessionID,
                    userName:req.body.username,
                    Email:req.user.email,
                    uid:req.user._id,
                    mobile:req.user.mobile,
                });
            });         
        }
    })(req, res, next);
});
```

### My collection look like below in mongoDB

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("57921ce8f8a10f644ababf2d"),
  "name": "abc",
  "email": "abc@gmail.com",
  "password": "32432423#fds#yy&1233S&dr&@",
  "mobile": "9886787560",
  "generatedOtp": "270371",
  "active": false,
  "__v": NumberInt(0) 
}
```

Now it will check username and password if they are right then login otherwise it will shows that messages. Like this i want to check that `active` field also. Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below code should fit your needs.
Please note that I also removed the check `if (user) { ...` before checking the password as that is not necessary. If `user` would be `null` / `undefined` then your code would not reach that point due to your first check of `if (!user) { ...` which returns from the function in that case.

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField: 'username', 
    passwordField: 'password'},
    function(username, password, done) {
        User.findOne({ name : username}, function(err, user) {
            if (!user){
                return done(null, false,{message: 'Incorrect username' });
            } 

            if (!user.active) {
                return done(null, false, {message: 'User is inactive'});
            }

            var validPassword = user.comparePassword(password);
            if(!validPassword){
                return done(null, false,{message: 'Incorrect password' });
            }

            return done(null, user);
        });       
    }
));
```